# Randomly distribute a string in column

Tags: pandas, data-science

I have a dataset in this form

```
Name        Age
Aaron       42
Steve       44
Richard     29
```

I have to create a new column and I have to fill that column using strings.. The column name will be 'vaccinated_or_not' and it should have values 'Yes', 'No', 'Info Missing', 'Not Provided', 'In Progress'.... So, I have to fill this column 'vaccinated_or_not' using these 5 strings randomly... Can someone pls help me out on how to achieve it..

Final dataset should be like this:

```
Name        Age   Vaccinaited_or_not
Aaron       42      Yes
Steve       44      Info Missing
Richard     29      No
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`np.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
choices = ['Yes', 'No', 'Info Missing', 'Not Provided', 'In Progress']
df['Vaccinaited_or_not'] = np.random.choice(choices, len(df))
print(df)

# Output
      Name  Age Vaccinaited_or_not
0    Aaron   42        In Progress
1    Steve   44       Not Provided
2  Richard   29       Info Missing
```

You can also provide weights:

```
choices = ['Yes', 'No', 'Info Missing', 'Not Provided', 'In Progress']
weights = [0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.1]  # sum=1
df['Vaccinaited_or_not'] = np.random.choice(choices, len(df), p=weights)
```

**Best practice**: using [RandomGenerator](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html)

```
choices = ['Yes', 'No', 'Info Missing', 'Not Provided', 'In Progress']
weights = [0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.1]  # sum must be 1
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=2023)  # for reproducible case
df['Vaccinaited_or_not'] = rng.choice(choices, len(df), p=weights)
```

**Note about weights**: using weights/probabilities is important to make sense of your data:

```
x = pd.Series(rng.choice(choices, 10000, p=weights))
x.value_counts(normalize=True).plot.bar(rot=0, title='10000 samples')
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
import numpy as np

L = ['Yes', 'No', 'Info Missing','Not Provided','In Progress']
df['Vaccinaited_or_not'] = np.random.choice(L, size=len(df))

print (df)
      Name  Age Vaccinaited_or_not
0    Aaron   42       Not Provided
1    Steve   44        In Progress
2  Richard   29                Yes
```